# Delete entries from Friday to Sunday on an xts object

Tags: r, time, xts

My xts object looks like this:

```
                            BID     OFR     PRICE
    2015-01-01 13:15:00 1.48168 1.48285 0.3935712
    2015-01-01 13:20:00 1.48013 1.48102 0.3924305
    2015-01-01 13:25:00 1.47922 1.48012 0.3918190
    2015-01-01 13:30:00 1.47947 1.47970 0.3917616
    2015-01-01 13:35:00 1.48019 1.48046 0.3922617
       .
       .
       .
       .
```

I set the time zone to EST. How can I delete entries from Friday 17:05 , Eastern Time (EST) until Sunday 17:00, Easter Time (EST) as well? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explore the documentation in `xts` for `?.indexwday`.

You could do this, to get the data you want for your specified (forex) trading hours, assuming `dat` contains your `xts` time series:

```
is_fri <- .indexwday(dat) == 5 & (.indexhour(dat) >= 18 | .indexhour(dat) == 17 & .indexmin(dat) >= 5)
is_sat <- .indexwday(dat) == 6 
is_sun <- .indexwday(dat) == 0 & .indexhour(dat) <= 16

xts_data_you_want <- dat[!(is_fri | is_sat | is_sun)]
```

`.indexwday` returns 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, etc, for the timestamps in the `xts` object, and what should be self explanatory numeric values are also returned for `.indexmin`, `.indexhour`.

As a check, you can do `weekdays(index(dat))` to see `.indexwday` is returning what you expect for certain timestamps.

Comment: According to '.indexwday(dat)` Sunday is equivalent to `==0`. You have to switch `is_sun <- .indexwday(dat) == 7 & .indexhour(dat) <= 16` with `is_sun <- .indexwday(dat) == 0 & .indexhour(dat) <= 16`. Before running the code is essential to run `Sys.setenv(TZ="EST")` as the series are realised on this timezone.